# How to define stack size for particular thread with C++ boost library?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost

I need to increase the stack size of a `boost::thread` object. The thread's task is to store a large set 3D points, which is implemented recursively and thus needs quite some memory space on the stack.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Flashlight *flashlight = new Flashlight();
    flashlight->thread_group = new boost::thread_group();
    boost::thread::attributes attrs;
    attrs.set_stack_size(16*1024*1024);
    flashlight->orbslam_thread = new boost::thread(attrs, boost::bind(&Flashlight::orbslam_loop, flashlight));
    flashlight->thread_group->add_thread(flashlight->orbslam_thread);
    // initializing some more threads ...
    flashlight->thread_group->join_all();
    return 0;
}
```

A.) Did I increase the thread's stack size to 16MB correctly in the code listed above?

B.) Is it possible to read the attributes, in particular the current stack size, of a `boost::thread` object somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have set the stack size to 16M. This gives you the stack size.

```
std::cout << attrs.get_stack_size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Ok that will give me back the value I set before. How do I get the attributes of another `boost::thread` object not configured by myself?

Comment: OK. That you cannot do. There is no public interface, that gives you the stack size of some arbitrary thread. If you create all those threads yourself, you could keep track of the stack sizes you assigned to a thread with specific id. Some sort of registry, where the id of the thread is the key.

Comment: Thanks. I am asking since the increase of the stack size like I did in my original post did not lead to the desired effect. Therefore I need a confirmation that the code works or a possibility to validate that the thread has indeed the desired stack size.